# Iptables rules with ! character

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking

I have entered iptables rules to log a specific connection on our server, but it doesn't seem to be working as I want it to. Here are the rules:

```
1    LOG        tcp  -- !10.51.0.0/16         0.0.0.0/0           state NEW    tcp dpt:8040 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `New Connection_8040TCP: '
2    LOG        tcp  -- !192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8040 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `New Connection_8040TCP: '
```

Iptables should log only IP connections which are not in the specified networks, but it keeps logging all connections from all IP addresses.

Comment: How are you testing these rules? Are you sure it's not with established connections? Also, can you give us the `iptables` commands you are using to input the rules?

Comment: iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW ! --src 10.51.0.0/16 -p tcp --dport 8040 -j LOG --log-prefix "New Connection_8040TCP: "

Comment: I simply connect with an internal ip to test the rules. thanks

Comment: *Connexion* is a perfectly valid, if slightly old fashioned, alternate spelling of *connection*, @NathanC. Stack Exchange is not a sausage factory: people are permitted to express things in their preferred phrasing where that does not impede communication.

Comment: @TRiG Okay. You can roll it back if you feel that strongly about it.

Comment: Sorry English is not my native language, in french connection and connexion are the same.

Comment: They're the same in English too, @Bryan, but the *x* spelling is slightly old fashioned. Nothing wrong with it, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you can't refer multiple IP ranges in a single iptables rule, but using multiple rules indirectly leads to a disjunction (logical OR): connections will be logged if they match your first, OR your second rule.

What you want, is a conjunctive behavior (logical AND): new connections coming out of `10.51.0.0/16`, AND also out of `192.168.0.0/16`need to be logged.

This is why you can't find that simple solution which you want. There isn't.

But you can solve this by only a little bit more complex way. You can create a new chain:

```
iptables -N logger
iptables -A INPUT -j logger
iptables -A logger -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -A logger -s 10.51.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -A logger -j LOG
```

What these commands do:

1. they create a new table, named `logger`.
2. We set up iptables for every connection to try his table as well.
3. this logger table checks if your packets originating from your trusted networks (`192.168.0.0/16` and `10.51.0.0/16`). If yes, all goes normally (the `RETURN` target gives back the control to the originating table).
4. If not, the connection is logged (and, as we are on the end of the table, the control also returns to the origin).

As a side effect, you can later use this new table for other tasks as well - for example, to REJECT packets or any other purpose. On my opinion the best if we see iptables as if it were some like a simple programming language.

Comment: Thank you Peterh, that's exactly what i needed. It's working great.

Comment: @Bryan Thank you very much! If you are satisfied with an answer, you can (should) accept it by clicking the pipe icon on the left side. It is a big reward to the answering person. (Thanks!)

Comment: @Bryan And now you reached the 15 reputation point. From now, you can upvote questions and answers, if you think they deserve it.

Answer (score 6):

Incoming connections are always going to match one of those rules aren't they?

A connection from `10.51.0.1` for example won't get logged by the first rule but will hit the second one.

Don't you need the equivalent of `!10.51.0.0/16 && !192.168.0.0/16` (probably not valid syntax but correct logically).

Comment: To my mind, you've hit the nail on the head.  +1 from me.

Comment: Just accept the connections for the networks, and then log in a third rule.

Comment: @wurtel ACCEPT-ing can cause harmful interference, for example if he has later some DROP rules.

Comment: Paul Haldane, you were right, and peterh give the tricks. Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

Depending on version and distribution, sometimes you have to activate the iprange extension:

`iptables -A INPUT -s ! 10.51.0.0/16 -m iprange -j LOG`

Comment: It will log the 192.168.0.0/16 connections too, which contradicts the wish of the OP. Anyways isn't clear why you need the iprange module for this simple rule.

Comment: This was just an example, of course you have to add the second range, too. On some older distribution you have to activate the iprange module as it is not active by default.